# 4 channel multiplexer example circuit looks strange

Tags: multiplexer

I have a 4-channel [TMUX1109PWR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmux1109.pdf?ts=1640986528671) multiplexer and from the example circuits and instructions on the datasheet I have made a circuit.  The circuit controls the UART connections to an MC.  When a USB is plugged in connections from the USB are prioritized for firmware updates.  As soon as USB_VDD is detected channel 4A will flow to drain A and 4B will flow to drain B.  When USB_VDD is not detected channel 1A and 1B will be flowing to the drains A and B.

[image: logic]
[image: circuit]

My confusion is in examples such as the one below VSS has a 0.1uF capacitor, but is connected directly to "the most negative power supply" so this leads to a ground connection on my board.  But what is the purpose of connecting directly to ground and also having a capacitor connecting to VSS and GND, like in my circuit.
[image: example]

Comment: As per the datasheet "Negative power supply. This pin is the most negative power-supply potential. For reliable operation, connect a decoupling capacitor ranging from 0.1 µF to 10 µF between VSS and GND.VSS can be connected to ground for single supply applications" Always read the datasheet.

Comment: I read this in the datasheet and even quoted it in my second paragraph.  But this does not answer my question.

Comment: "connect a decoupling capacitor..." Read up on the function of decoupling capacitors. In addition this is only needed for a split rail PSU

Comment: Also from your schematic it looks like you using a single supply. So you only need to ground Vss and do not require the decoupling capacitor. As mentioned in the datasheet the decoupling cap is only needed for dual rail supplies (+5V and -5V for example)